# Generating candlestick data from trades

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

## Intro

I've imported the historical market data of the Kraken exchange into a PostgreSQL database.

The dataset is available here:

https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047543791-Downloadable-historical-market-data-time-and-sales

## The Schema

The `Trades` table looks like this:

```
kraken-trades=# \d "Trades"
                                     Table "public.Trades"
  Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 Id        | integer                  |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 SymbolId  | integer                  |           | not null |
 Price     | numeric                  |           | not null |
 Quantity  | numeric                  |           | not null |
 TimeStamp | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 Side      | order_side               |           | not null |
 Type      | order_type_minimal       |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "PK_Trades" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("Id")
    "IX_Trades_Price" btree ("Price")
    "IX_Trades_SymbolId" btree ("SymbolId")
    "IX_Trades_TimeStamp" btree ("TimeStamp")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "FK_Trades_Symbols_SymbolId" FOREIGN KEY ("SymbolId") REFERENCES "Symbols"("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Excerpt of the table:

```
kraken-trades=# SELECT * FROM "Trades" LIMIT 10;
 Id | SymbolId |  Price  |   Quantity   |       TimeStamp        | Side | Type
----+----------+---------+--------------+------------------------+------+-------
  1 |        1 | 2.36400 |  29.18557000 | 2021-08-10 08:31:26-07 | buy  | limit
  2 |        1 | 2.36400 |  12.50281000 | 2021-08-10 08:31:34-07 | buy  | limit
  3 |        1 | 2.36300 | 416.76043000 | 2021-08-10 08:31:36-07 | buy  | limit
  4 |        1 | 2.36500 |  38.94156000 | 2021-08-10 08:32:00-07 | buy  | limit
  5 |        1 | 2.36300 |   0.41676000 | 2021-08-10 08:32:05-07 | buy  | limit
  6 |        1 | 2.36200 | 161.54216000 | 2021-08-10 08:32:07-07 | buy  | limit
  7 |        1 | 2.36200 | 675.29737511 | 2021-08-10 08:32:08-07 | buy  | limit
  8 |        1 | 2.53000 |  11.68247000 | 2021-08-10 08:32:13-07 | buy  | limit
  9 |        1 | 2.53000 |  77.88313000 | 2021-08-10 08:32:18-07 | buy  | limit
 10 |        1 | 2.36000 |  29.23506000 | 2021-08-10 08:32:22-07 | buy  | limit
(10 rows)
```

I currently have `41,695,261` items in the table for `XBTUSD` (i.e. *Bitcoin*):

```
kraken-trades=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Trades" WHERE "SymbolId" = (SELECT "Id" FROM "Symbols" WHERE "Name" = 'XBTUSD');
  count
----------
 41695261
```

## Generating candlesticks

Here's a query which generates the monthly [candlestick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) data (aka *OHLC* or *kline* data) for `XBTUSD`:

```
SELECT 
    date, trade_count, low, high, 
    trades_open."Price"  AS open_price,
    trades_close."Price" AS close_price
FROM
(
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', "TimeStamp") AS date,
    COUNT(*)                      AS trade_count,

    min( "TimeStamp" ) open_timestamp,
    max( "TimeStamp" ) close_timestamp,

    min( "Price" ) AS low,
    max( "Price" ) AS high
FROM "Trades"
WHERE "SymbolId" = (SELECT "Id" FROM "Symbols" WHERE "Name" = 'XBTUSD')
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "TimeStamp")
) tbl

JOIN "Trades" trades_open  ON tbl.open_timestamp  = trades_open."TimeStamp"
JOIN "Trades" trades_close ON tbl.close_timestamp = trades_close."TimeStamp";
```

Example of the results:

[image]

The query currently runs in about 7 minutes:

```
Time: 439791.175 ms (07:19.791)
```

Explanation:

For each month, we show the:

- Opening price
- Closing price
- Highest price
- Lowest price

## Question

Is there a more efficient way to go about performing this query?

**Update**:

I noticed that the query above is actually producing duplicate entries for a given month. See for example:

[image]

## The project

The entire C# project which was used to create the database and import the data is here:

https://github.com/dharmatech/kraken-trades-database/tree/009-postgresql

The entity models and database context:

https://github.com/dharmatech/kraken-trades-database/blob/009-postgresql/KrakenTradesDatabase/Model.cs

Answer (score 1):

By adding a WHERE clause after the join to narrow the data a bit:

```sql
WHERE 
trades_open."SymbolId" = (SELECT "Id" FROM "Symbols" WHERE "Name" = 'XBTUSD')
AND
trades_close."SymbolId" = (SELECT "Id" FROM "Symbols" WHERE "Name" = 'XBTUSD')
```

I got the query down to 2 minutes:

```
Time: 126672.294 ms (02:06.672)
```

The full query:

```sql
SELECT
    date, trade_count, low, high, 
    open_price,
    close_price
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        date, trade_count, low, high, 
        trades_open."Price"  AS open_price,
        trades_close."Price" AS close_price,

        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS n
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            date_trunc('month', "TimeStamp") AS date,
            COUNT(*)                         AS trade_count,

            min( "TimeStamp" ) open_timestamp,
            max( "TimeStamp" ) close_timestamp,

            min( "Price" ) AS low,
            max( "Price" ) AS high
        FROM "Trades"
        WHERE "SymbolId" = (SELECT "Id" FROM "Symbols" WHERE "Name" = 'XBTUSD')
        GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "TimeStamp")
    ) tbl

    JOIN "Trades" trades_open  ON tbl.open_timestamp  = trades_open."TimeStamp"
    JOIN "Trades" trades_close ON tbl.close_timestamp = trades_close."TimeStamp"
    WHERE 
    trades_open."SymbolId" = (SELECT "Id" FROM "Symbols" WHERE "Name" = 'XBTUSD')
    AND
    trades_close."SymbolId" = (SELECT "Id" FROM "Symbols" WHERE "Name" = 'XBTUSD')  
) AS tbl_2
WHERE n = 1
ORDER BY date;
```

More efficient queries are still welcome. :-)

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW `PostgreSQL 14.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

Comment: Can you go to dbfiddle.uk and put in  your trade table and some sample data. I'm unclear as to why you're joining back to your trades table twice? Try using a generated column of trunc_date(month, ts) and index it. Put the symbol in the trade table - it's only a few bytes.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6cVGoLkYVuwwdk8uZHYeEx/3

Comment: In that query, I use a candle size of `minute` instead of `month` since it's a small dataset that I've provided there.

Comment: There's a few ideas [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ff1558fbe92d980376f4c0b32ddeb703), but bear in mind that performance tests with so few records are meaningless. What I think would make a **big** difference in your scenario is partitioning. If you can point me to a download of the the full data from your two tables that require **no** data scrubbing, I'll try and run my ideas here on my local machine.

Comment: How many records are there in the trades table (and symbols) - put that info into the question. One further point, don't use SQL keywords (such as `date` and `timestamp` for column names - or aliases) and there's no need to use quoting for table names - it merely clutters up your SQL! Am I correct in assuming that these tables are never (or very rarely) updated?

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW I've exported 841314 trades and made it available here: [xbtusd-trades.sql.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjlM3TqVAvfOh8tXvfW8k9gOJC44pQ?e=rkb7VF). It's all the trades in the month of 2021-09. So you may want to change the query to have daily candlesticks instead of monthly.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW You'll have to change the `Side` and `Type` columns in `Trades` to `text` since you won't have those enum types. (They aren't used in the query.)

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW Even if you don't get to explore this further, thank you for taking already taking a look thus far.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW When I run the same query I posted in the answer on the sample data I just linked, it takes over a minute, so that should be a decent dataset to test with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132180/discussion-between-verace-get-vaccinated-now-and-dharmatech).

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW I totally don't expect you to do this but... If you really were curious about downloading the entire dataset, I've provided instructions in this [README](https://github.com/dharmatech/kraken-trades-database). The project is in C# and requires dotnet.